# cloudinary: "uploaded_file = params[:person][:picture].path" works on local but not on heroku deploy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cloudinary

Uploading image via cloudinary works on localhost, but not when rails app is deployed on heroku. (i.e. 'We are sorry but something went wrong")

Code: uploaded_file = params[:log][:picture].path 
cloudinary_file = Cloudinary::Uploader.upload(uploaded_file, :folder => "journal-on-rails").

I have pinpointed that doing a printout of uploaded_file shows "/var/folders/2f/..." in local, but "/tmp/RackMultipart20190606-4-1i7nfxh.jpg" in heroku.

in logs_controller.rb file:

```
def update
    @log = Log.find(params[:id])

    if params[:log][:picture]
      p "begin cloudinary upload if there is image: "
      uploaded_file = params[:log][:picture].path
      p "printing uploaded_file path below: "
      p uploaded_file
      cloudinary_file = Cloudinary::Uploader.upload(uploaded_file, :folder => "journal-on-rails")

      p "printing cloudinary_file below: "
      p cloudinary_file

      p "printing cloudinary_file url below: "
      p cloudinary_file["url"]


      @log.attributes = {:image => cloudinary_file["public_id"]}
    else
      log_params[:image] = @log.image
    end

    respond_to do |format|
      if @log.update(log_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @log, notice: "Entry updated!" }
        p "Log updated!"
      else
        format.html { render action: 'logs/edit' }
      end
    end
  end
```

In edit.html.erb file:

```
<<%= form_with scope: :log, model: @log, local: true do |form| %>
  <p>
    <%= form.label :title, 'Entry Title' %><br>
    <%= form.text_field :title, class: "title-text-field" %><br>
        <%= form.label :content, "Content - Great! Felt better?" %><br>
        <%= form.text_area :content, class: "log-text-area"%><br>
        <%= form.label :picture %><br>
        <%= cl_image_tag(@log.image, :width => 350, :fetch_format=>:auto, :crop=>"scale") %><br>
    <%= form.file_field :picture %><br>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= form.submit %>
  </p>
<% end %>

<%= link_to 'Back', log_path, class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
```

My heroku Journal on Rails web app: https://agenda-journal-on-rails.herokuapp.com/

In localhost, I can create a title, a body, and also upload an image via Cloudinary. The root route shows a list of journal entries/logs, with a thumbnail of the uploaded image. But in heroku, when deployed in production, none of the cloudinary functions are able to work. As a result, there is no thumbnail.

I have concluded that the cl_image_tag() helper method from Cloudinary is working. Because I can get it to fetch another public_id in my cloudinary account. But in Heroku, when doing POST method for edit. I get this error inside 'heroku logs --tail':

2019-06-06T05:18:07.303488+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/logs/3" host=agenda-journal-on-rails.herokuapp.com request_id=f7c5bdff-79e2-4f28-b500-f5ffecdc4246 fwd="129.126.207.229" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=819ms status=500 bytes=1827 protocol=https

Comment: did you configure all the env variables on Heroku for Cloudinary?

Comment: Yes, I did. So in the heroku account, I went to the dashboard for this app, and used the 'settings' tab to input my CLOUDINARY_URL key-value pair. Per cloudinary documentation, regards to API_KEY, they will always look for the CLOUDINARY_URL set in ENV first. There is no issue with connection to cloudinary, otherwise, I would not able to load the logs#index root route in the first place since it has the cl_image_tag() helper function that relies on cloudinary.

Comment: you seams not to have configured cloudinary properly. check again